# Are there any popular libraries to handle writing XSDs in Java without using binding?

Tags: java, xml

I'm currently scraping a bunch of interfaces and building basic XSDs from the information that I derive. I was wondering if anyone knows of a good simple library that I could use to build basic XSDs programatically from the list of simple parameters found by my application. I could do this by simply outputting the variable name and wrapping it in the XSD syntax like this `<xs:element name="derivedKey" type="xs:string">` but I'd prefer that some library do this for me in case I decide to do something fancier down the road. Does anyone know of a good library to handle write XSDs without binding them to objects?

Comment: What's wrong with JAXB's schema generation?

Comment: I guess I assumed that JAXB's schema generator requires object binding. Maybe I should give it another look. I wasn't aware JAXB had support for non-binding related XSD generation. I guess it makes sense that they would.

Comment: As far as I can tell, XSD generation in JAXB requires that you start with a class. I don't think it was intended to be used for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache XML Schema](http://ws.apache.org/commons/xmlschema20/) will definitely solve your problem, i think. You want a Java library so that you create XSD easily and effective way.

Apache XML Scema provides all those features that you need. Apart from that it can also read an XSD, analyse it and modify the same.